# Android AdviewAds without a XML layout?

Tags: android, layout, admob

Im trying to publish an Adview ad to my app. The problem is, a particular section only uses an expandable list adaptor programatically for its layout, and no xml or layouts are used at all. Looking at the examples, it seems that you need a layout to apply the ad to:
http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html

Is there a way to do this without a layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely place the ad programmatically. Look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300459/how-do-i-add-the-admob-view-when-my-main-view-is-like-this) to a similar SO question.